# Ajax.BeginForm is not running "OnSuccess" function

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am experience a strange problem when trying to use MVC Ajax helpers. I have no problem making an ajax post in jquery itself but I want to avoid having to manually fetch all my forms parameters.

**The symptoms**
Instead of my OnSuccess function being ran asp literally renders my Json object like this.
[image]

Here are the key snippets to my code. I have to be missing something trivial.

**View**

```
 @using (Ajax.BeginForm("ParkingRequest", null, new AjaxOptions()
            {
                HttpMethod = "POST",
                OnSuccess = "SaveComplete",
            }, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
            {
```

**Javascript**

```
function SaveComplete(result)
    {
        if(result.success == true)
        {
            $("#confirmation-message").fadeIn();
        }
        else
        {
            if(result.reason != "You should only be selecting one date.")
            {
                $("#failure-message").fadeIn();
            }
            else
            {
                //user somehow bypassed javascript and tried to enter multiple dates
                alert(result.reason);
            }

        }
    }
```

**Controller**

```
 public async Task<JsonResult> ParkingRequest(Models.FormsViewModels.ParkingRequestEditViewModel vm)
 return Json(new
        {
            success = true
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but I recently had this very same issue. I assume you have already found a suitable solution by now, but I'll leave this here in case anyone else comes across something similar.

How are you submitting the form? In my case, I wanted the form to submit whenever anything changed (in this case, the form was only a couple of checkboxes) My problem was that I was trying to submit the form via javascript, like so:

```
<input type="checkbox" onchange="this.form.submit();" ... />
```

For whatever reason, it seems like the unobtrusive-ajax library doesn't submit a form asynchronously if triggered via javascript. It *will* submit asynchronously if triggered via an HTML submit button, however.

To workaround this for my use case, I added a hidden submit button to the form and changed my javascript to click it onchange:

```
<input type="checkbox" onchange="document.getElementById('clicker').click()" ... />
<input id="clicker" type="submit" style="display:none;" />
```

Voila! The AJAX helper actually submits asynchronously now. Yeah, I know it's a little hacky but it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

The form is actually submitting a non-async POST request. The javascript isn't intercepting it.

Check that you have included the necessary jQuery libraries and that there are no javascript errors being thrown.

Comment: I just did a double check on the libraries and everything definitely is there with no errors being thrown.

Comment: Can you put a breakpoint on the document events that are in `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` and see what is happening?

Answer (score 0):

You might be missing including jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js file or rendering jqeryval try this

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
```

> OR in _Layout.cshtml

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
```

> And Async method should be

```
public async Task<JsonResult> ParkingRequest(Models.FormsViewModels.ParkingRequestEditViewModel  vm)
    {
        // do stuff here....
        var result = await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            return Json(new { success = true });
        });

        return result;
    }
```

other wise you will endup with warning.
but I would suggest you to go with Ajax Jquery requests only.
Hope it helps you

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have included the following script to your page:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

and that you have enabled unobtrusive javascript in your web.config:

```
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
```

This is what makes Ajax.* helpers such as Ajax.BeginForm to work.